# Can TFS & Visual studio generate branch timeline diagrams?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, branching-and-merging

Is it possible for the branching diagrams to be automatically generated by Visual studio (using info from TFS)?  I know there are simple tools like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465202), but they have no dates!  and they don't show when it was merged back into the trunk branch.

I'd love for it to generate a diagram like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyJ8B.png

It needs to have dates of when the original branch was made (from trunk)... and when it was merged back into trunk.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on a changeset and select "track changeset" you get a view of where the changeset is and where it has been merged. You can then switch to Timeline View and see this overlayed on a timeline with dates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405662.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line tool for TFS that at the very least can show you all of the branches that came off of trunk (and their children).  It is:

```
tf branches <YourTrunkBranchPathHere>
```